# Why is my PHP post function format like this when received in NodeJS Express?

Tags: php, node.js, json, express, curl

guys, I am quite new to PHP and have a function that is trying to post data to my backend NodeJS Express API endpoint.

The received **req.body** became like this when I received it.
It appended the extra **{ jsonObj :""}**

```
{{"name":"PHP Game test","email":"test@test.ca","logo":"logo.jpg","heroImage":"hero.jpg","teamName":"test","teamSize":"4","type":"publisher","mainContacts":{"name":"Steven Zhou","phone":"7788889128","email":"info@appcodes.io"},"teamAdvisors":"TBD","addresses":{"street":"11451 4th ave","province":"BC","country":"Canada","zipcode":"V7E3H1"},"url":"appcodes.io","officeLocations":"5","gamesProduced":"2","gamesInDevelopment":"3","description":"Test API"}: ""}
```

I want it to be like this format

```
{"name":"PHP Game test","email":"test@test.ca","logo":"logo.jpg","heroImage":"hero.jpg","teamName":"test","teamSize":"4","type":"publisher","mainContacts":{"name":"Steven Zhou","phone":"7788889128","email":"info@appcodes.io"},"teamAdvisors":"TBD","addresses":{"street":"11451 4th ave","province":"BC","country":"Canada","zipcode":"V7E3H1"},"url":"appcodes.io","officeLocations":"5","gamesProduced":"2","gamesInDevelopment":"3","description":"Test API"}
```

Here is my PHP code thats sending the POST request

```
$data = [
        'name' => 'PHP Game test',
        'email' => 'test@test.ca',
        'logo' => 'logo.jpg',
        'heroImage' => 'hero.jpg',
        'teamName' => 'test',
        'teamSize' => '4',
        "type" => "publisher",
        "mainContacts"=> [
            "name"=> "Steven Zhou",
            "phone"=> "7788889128",
            "email"=> "info@appcodes.io"
        ],
        "teamAdvisors"=> "TBD",
        "addresses"=> [
            "street"=> "11451 4th ave",
            "province"=> "BC",
            "country"=> "Canada",
            "zipcode"=> "V7E3H1"
        ],
        "url"=> "appcodes.io",
        "officeLocations"=> "5",
        "gamesProduced"=> "2",
        "gamesInDevelopment"=> "3",
        "description"=> "Test API"
    ];

    $jsonData = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:3006/api/company",
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonData,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "contentType : application/json",
            "Accept: */*",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
            "api-key: ..."
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $response;
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

When I don't use the **json_encode** function it would send the data correctly except the addresses and contacts became normal arrays without the keys like this

```
{"name":"PHP Game test","email":"test@test.ca","logo":"logo.jpg","heroImage":"hero.jpg","teamName":"test","teamSize":"4","type":"publisher","mainContacts":["Steven Zhou","7788889128","info@appcodes.io"],"teamAdvisors":"TBD","addresses":["11451 4th ave","BC","Canada","V7E3H1"],"url":"appcodes.io","officeLocations":"5","gamesProduced":"2","gamesInDevelopment":"3","description":"Test API"}
```

Here is the NodeJS Express endpoint that's receiving the request

```
router.post('/company', multer.none(), verifyWordpressApiKey, createCompany);


async function createCompany ( req, res, next){
    try{
        if(req.body.logo.length === 0) {
            return res.status(400).send({errorMessage: 'No company logo uploaded.'});
        } else if(req.body.heroImage.length === 0) {
            return res.status(400).send({errorMessage: 'No hero image uploaded.'});
        }

        req.body.createdBy = DB_WORDPRESS_USER;
        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(req.body.mainContacts);
        const organizationResult = await createOrganizationFromPipedrive(req.body.name);
        await createNewPersonFromPipedrive(organizationResult.id,
            jsonObj[0],
            jsonObj[1],
            jsonObj[2]);
        await createInternalCompany(req.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }catch (error) {
        next(new Error('Unable to create a new company' + error));
    }
}
```

It's been very puzzling, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `let jsonObj = JSON.parse(req.body.mainContacts);` - if you are able to access `req.body.mainContacts` there, it must mean your request body has already been parsed as JSON. (Or something else.) So why are you trying to decode this value _again_ now? The content of the `mainContacts` item in your input data was _not_ a string containing JSON, but that would be the only case in which what you are trying to do would make any sense.

Comment: Maybe spelling the name of the request header `content-type` correctly would be a good start here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `contentType` to  [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) in your `CURL` request

and make sure in Express you're using

```
app.use(express.json());// this will format all incoming request as JSON
```

Comment: I tried, but still having the same problem